# How can I make my jump and land animations play reliably?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I can't make my jump and land animations play reliably Currently the jump animation doesn't play and the land animation seems to play randomly.

I've been working with unity 3d for several months but I am new to using animations. I may just be missing some basic information.

At one point the jump animation would play, but only after the player was in the air. How do I make animations play at the right time reliably?

This is my player movement script where I'm currently calling the jump and land animations from.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMvmt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody player;
    public float sideForce = 5;
    public float jumpForce = 5;
    public float fallingForce = 10;
    public SphereCollider col;
    public LayerMask groundLayers;
    public Animator jump;
    public Animator land;


    private void Start()
    {
        jump = GetComponent<Animator>();
        land = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if ( Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            player.AddForce(-sideForce, 0, 0);
        }

        if ( Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            player.AddForce(sideForce, 0, 0);
        }

        if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            jump.SetBool("playJump",true);
            Invoke("StopJumpAnimation", .4f);
            player.AddForce(0, jumpForce, 0);
        }

        OncollisionEnter();


        if (IsGrounded() == false)
        {
            player.AddForce(0, -fallingForce, 0);
        }

    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics.CheckCapsule(col.bounds.center,
            new Vector3(col.bounds.center.x,
            col.bounds.min.y, col.bounds.center.z), col.radius * .9f, groundLayers);

    }

    void StopJumpAnimation()
    {
        jump.SetBool("playJump", false);
    }

    void StopLandAnimation()
    {
       land.SetBool("playLand", false);
    }

    void OncollisionEnter()
    {
        land.SetBool("playLand", true);
        Invoke("StopLandAnimation", .3f);
    }
}
```

I can show you pictures of the animator if that helps. I might just need a basic explanation of how to use the animator since I'm new to animation.

Comment: Can you screenshot us your animation controller in the unity window? preferably with how you setup the transition states; (Aka the arrows as well as the inspector when you click on those arrows.)

Comment: I've actually fixed it in the time since I posted this. Thank You!

Comment: @games247 This is a community for **knowledge-sharing** through a Q&A format. Please _share_ your understanding what **what** the issue was, and **how** you fixed it.

Comment: `jump = GetComponent<Animator>(); land = GetComponent<Animator>();` ... for what reason do you store the **same** reference under two different names? In general your setup looks like you would be better using **Triggers** instead of **Bools** here